# Find all html characters in drop-down option text and replace them via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a dropdown menu that pulls in text from a database column.  The database column can include HTML mark-up.  In the drop-down I obviously don't need that in the text.  I am working on some jquery and it partially accomplished what I'm looking for.  However, it seems to only be replacing the first instance of each character

```
$('select option').each(function() { 
    this.text = this.text.replace('&nbsp;', ' ');
    this.text = this.text.replace('<div>', '' );
    this.text = this.text.replace('</div>', '' );
});
```

Here is the HTML for the drop-down:

```
<select name="ctl00$SubPageBody$ClassList" id="ctl00_SubPageBody_ClassList">
<option value="196">Four Week Series: July 19, 2012, 11:00am-12:00pm&<div>July 26, 2012, 11:00am-12:00pm&nbsp;</div><div>August 2, 2012, 11:00am-12:00pm</div><div>August 9, 2012, 11:00am-12:00pm</div></option>

</select>
```

Comment: It would make more sense to do this on the server-side. The server-side script that generates the HTML source code should do this task.

Comment: I think it's better to strip out unnecessary markup on server side script

Comment: Coudn't agree more, unfortunately I'm having trouble getting the source from the developer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why there would be HTML within an `<option>` element to begin with but...

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hfH5S/)

```
$('select option').each(function() { 
    this.text = $(this).text();       
});
```

Comment: You can see I have that implemented here: http://midwestanxiety.com/TrainingDetails.aspx?ID=59, however it isn't working, any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why the above didn't work (works in the jsfiddle), try: `this.text = $(this).html(this.text).text();`

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions to replace all instances and do whatever fancy stuff you want:

http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-replace

For example, this will replace 'hello' and/or 'wo':

```
var s = 'hello world hello';
var s = s.replace(/hello|wo/g, '');
```

Just keep in mind, you can't parse HTML with regexes :)

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

I agree that doing this on the server side would be more appropriate.

If you have to do it with Javascript though, you can use regular expressions:

```
$(this).text().replace(/REPLACEME/g, 'repclacement');
```

Mind the g at the end of the RegEx: it's the global flag.

You will also need to escape some special characters like /.
So  would be </div>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /g option in regex to replace all instances on a line.

```
this.text = this.text.replace(/<\/div>/g, '' );
```

Notice that / replaces ' when you want to find with regex.